# Proceed too long

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this code

```
For lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
Set workrange = Cells(lrow, 5)
Set workrange2 = Cells(lrow, 10)
If workrange.Value = "100" _
 And workrange2.Value = "0" _
        Then workrange.EntireRow.Delete
Next lrow
For lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
Set workrange = Cells(lrow, 5)
Set workrange2 = Cells(lrow, 10)
If workrange.Value = "105" _
 And workrange2.Value = "0" _
        Then workrange.EntireRow.Delete
Next lrow
For lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
Set workrange = Cells(lrow, 5)
Set workrange2 = Cells(lrow, 10)
If workrange.Value = "113" _
 And workrange2.Value = "0" _
        Then workrange.EntireRow.Delete
Next lrow
For lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
Set workrange = Cells(lrow, 5)
Set workrange2 = Cells(lrow, 10)
If workrange.Value = "120" _
 And workrange2.Value = "0" _
        Then workrange.EntireRow.Delete
Next lrow
For lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
Set workrange = Cells(lrow, 5)
Set workrange2 = Cells(lrow, 10)
If workrange.Value = "123" _
 And workrange2.Value = "0" _
        Then workrange.EntireRow.Delete
Next lrow
For lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
Set workrange = Cells(lrow, 5)
Set workrange2 = Cells(lrow, 10)
If workrange.Value = "124" _
 And workrange2.Value = "0" _
        Then workrange.EntireRow.Delete
Next lrow
For lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
Set workrange = Cells(lrow, 5)
Set workrange2 = Cells(lrow, 10)
If workrange.Value = "125" _
 And workrange2.Value = "0" _
        Then workrange.EntireRow.Delete
Next lrow
```

I am getting procedure too long because I have this same code but for multiple other values for the workrange.value part of the code. Is there any way to stream line this code so that any value I want for the workrange.value can be fit it with out having massive lines of code? Thanks!

Comment: You say you have 'multiple other values' but from a single instance we can't tell what the pattern is. Show us 3 or for examples of how your pattern works; most likely you will be able to do a simple loop instead of copy & pasting multiple times.

Comment: please see updated example

Comment: Is `I am getting procedure too long` an error of some sort or are you saying it's taking too long?

Comment: Procedure too long is an error in vba

Comment: @HHadden it is generally poor form to edit your question into something completely different like this. Your changes should not have been approved. Please revert this question to the prior version, and ask your new question separately.

Comment: Not sure how to revert my question. sorry I don't know your rules

Comment: I have reverted to the last version (will need to be approved) - please go ahead and ask your other question as a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this using loops, first keep in mind that you will want to limit your number of loops as much as possible - looping unnecessarily will take extra computing time. Generally speaking, we will creating a specific 'Array' of values which contains the entire list of all numbers you want to match against. We will create a loop which checks if the value equals any of the Array values, but before we do that loop, we will first check to see if the other value is 0.

I couldn't see a pattern that was followed in determining which values you cared about, so I showed how you would manually insert each value into the Array. If there is some pattern there I didn't see, this could be done differently. Alternatively, if you already have those numbers in Excel, you could make that Excel row/column a Named Range, and then loop through that without needing to create your own array.

**Edited the below to exit the For loop if it hits a match, to prevent attempting to check the value of a row which has been deleted**

```
Dim CheckArray() As Integer
Dim CheckArraySize As Integer
Dim ArrayCounter As Integer

CheckArraySize = 7
ReDim CheckArray(1, CheckArraySize)

CheckArray(1) = "100" 'Note that these are TEXT values, not numbers,
CheckArray(2) = "105" 'Per the examples in the OP
CheckArray(3) = "113"
CheckArray(4) = "120"
CheckArray(5) = "123"
CheckArray(6) = "124"
CheckArray(7) = "125"


For lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
    Set workrange = Cells(lrow, 5)
    Set workrange2 = Cells(lrow, 10)
    If workrange2.Value = "0" Then
        For ArrayCounter = 1 To CheckArraySize
            If workrange.Value = CheckArray(ArrayCounter) Then
                workrange.EntireRow.Delete
                ArrayCounter = CheckArraySize
            End If
        Next ArrayCounter
    End If
Next lrow
```

**Alternate Approach suggested in comments by @xidgel - will run faster**

```
Dim CheckArray() As Integer
Dim CheckArraySize As Integer
Dim ArrayCounter As Integer
Dim CheckString as String

CheckArraySize = 7
ReDim CheckArray(1, CheckArraySize)

CheckArray(1) = "100" 'Note that these are TEXT values, not numbers,
CheckArray(2) = "105" 'Per the examples in the OP
CheckArray(3) = "113"
CheckArray(4) = "120"
CheckArray(5) = "123"
CheckArray(6) = "124"
CheckArray(7) = "125"

For ArrayCounter = 1 to CheckArraySize
    CheckString = CheckString & CheckArray(ArrayCounter) &":"
Next ArrayCounter 'This loops to create a single string which contains all values that you want to check against

For lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
    Set workrange = Cells(lrow, 5)
    Set workrange2 = Cells(lrow, 10)
    If workrange2.Value = "0" Then
        If InStr(1, CheckString, workrange.Value) > 0 Then 'checks if workrange is found in the compilation of all array values
            workrange.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End If
Next lrow
```

**2nd EDIT to reflect the fact that the 'search terms' are already located in Excel**

This method works basically the same as above, except that instead of defining your new array, you will simply call the Array from Excel, where it is already stored. You say the 'search terms' are already in another workbook. I assume they are in a single column. Copy that column to your current workbook, let's say in sheet2! column A. Select all of those entries; go to the Formulas ribbon -> Name Manager ->New Name. Call this new name CheckArray. To refer to this new name in VBA, you can simply call Sheets(2).Range("CheckArray"). Everything else will basically be identical to the above, with only the beginning assignment of the CheckString changing, like so [also remove the "Dim CheckArray() statement]:

```
CheckArraySize = Sheets(2).Range("CheckArray").Rows.Count

For ArrayCounter = 1 to CheckArraySize
    CheckString = CheckString & Sheets(2).Range("CheckArray")(ArrayCounter,1) &":"
Next ArrayCounter
```

Apart from how you pull the string values into your CheckString, the rest of the code will be the same.

Comment: In HHadden's original question workrange was tested for string values --- this solution tests them against integers. Also, you could eliminate the inside loop by concatening all the test values to one long string say "100:105:113:..." and then test with Instr

Comment: Agreed on both points - @HHaden please clarify whether you are checking to see if there is TEXT which says "100", or a number with a value of 100.00. For the Instr method, I agree that would be simpler; I will give an alternative approach that shows this.

Comment: One subtle difference is that HHadden's original code does not appear to update LastRow and FirstRow. If a For/Next loop deleted rows, the subsequent For/Next loop will examine rows not examined by the previous one. I don't know if that's a feature or a bug in HHadden's original code.

Comment: I have the data in excel already but I need to make sure it is comparing that value I already have in excel and making sure the other value is equal to zero as well. How would I do this with a named range? Also I am looking to see if it is text in a column that says 100. Not all of the codes are numerical, for example some of the other codes are PTO, WKD and HRS

Comment: @HHadden if you are using text then I recommend you go with the second option above; if you don't have more than a couple dozen different text strings to check for then I recommend that you not bother with using a named range or something like that.

Comment: My array would by 417 values. Would that allow it to run still?

Comment: @HHadden Ooh, that's too much of a pain to do by hand, for sure. Where are the values located? Are they in Excel yet? Are they already located in a text string, like in a word file?

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon They are in a different excel file but I can easily copy them into the file I am working in

Comment: @HHadden Check my edits to the above - using a Named range will prevent you from needing to type any of this manually.

Comment: Unfortunately it is yet too be solved. I am getting a runtime error 1004 at the checkarrarysize part of the code

Comment: @HHadden Are you sure you put the named range on sheet2 [And by this I mean, whatever the 2nd sheet you have is, because the method above says Sheets(2).Range] , and named it exactly the same way you named it in VBA? I rechecked this reference method and confirmed it works on my end.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon                                                                                                   I did and that solved that problem but now I am getting the same error on the set workrange part of the code. Sorry I am new to this whole thing

Comment: @HHadden that's not my code, that's what you had originally. Please post a new question which asks to solve this new problem. Happy I was able to help you with this part of it.

Comment: I was actually able to figure it out. I believe I marked the question as solved but if I didn't please let me know